# why is my while loop never false(Python3)?

Tags: python

why is my code not working? I try to translate some words. Always if you type a "wrong" word. It should give you a new type field. If your word is in the dict it should translate it. But why it isn't working?

```
bedeutungen= {"computer": "Elektronische Rechenanlage", "handy": "Kleines Funktelefon, dass man bei sich trägt", "laptop": "flacher, tragbarer, Personal Computer"}

print("Verfügbare Wörter sind: Computer, Handy, Laptop")

eingabe = str(input("Welches Wort möchten Sie wissen: "))
eingabe= eingabe.lower()  
uebersetzung = ''



while eingabe.isdigit():
    eingabe = int(eingabe)
    print("Dies ist kein Wort")
    eingabe = str(input("Welches Wort möchten Sie übersetzen: "))



while eingabe != bedeutungen:

    print("Dieses Wort ist nicht vergeben!")
    eingabe = str(input("Welches Wort möchten Sie wissen: "))


uebersetzung = bedeutungen[eingabe]
print(uebersetzung)
```

Comment: How can eingabe be equal to a dict?

Comment: Please don't add fake "tags" to your title. That's what the actual _tags_ are for. If you try to remove "(Python3)" you'll find that your title is rejected outright. That's a good sign that either (a) it's not a good title or (b) you'll find answers if you search for existing questions. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to compare a string to a dictionary:

```
eingabe != bedeutungen:
```

this is always True, therefore an infinite circle.

You could simplify it to just:

```
if eingabe in bedeutungen:
    uebersetzung = bedeutungen[eingabe]
    print(uebersetzung)
```

And if you want to make your code even shorter you could simplify it to:

```
eingabe = str(input("Welches Wort möchten Sie wissen: ")).lower()

if eingabe in bedeutungen:
    print(bedeutungen[eingabe])
```

P.S. also it is preferrable to name your functions and variables in English (and not in German in that case). You could use `meanings`, `translation` and for example `inpt` for  `eingabe`

Here is the code which would try to translate it again if the input is not in the dictionary:

```
meanings = {"computer": "Elektronische Rechenanlage",
        "handy": "Kleines Funktelefon, dass man bei sich trägt",
        "laptop": "flacher, tragbarer, Personal Computer"}


def print_translation(inpt):
    if inpt in meanings:
        print(meanings[inpt])
    elif inpt.isdigit():
        print("Dies ist kein Wort")
        inpt = str(input("Welches Wort möchten Sie übersetzen: "))
        print_translation(inpt)
    else:
        print("Dieses Wort ist nicht vergeben!")
        inpt = str(input("Welches Wort möchten Sie wissen: "))
        print_translation(inpt)


print("Verfügbare Wörter sind: Computer, Handy, Laptop")
print_translation(str(input("Welches Wort möchten Sie wissen: ")).lower())
```

Comment: But if I just use "if" it will not print an input again if I type something, that is not in the dictionary.
I tried to use

```
while not eingabe in bedeutungen.keys().

```

yes that's true. I will try to type next time in English :P

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
if eingabe in bedeutungen:
    uebersetzung = bedeutungen[eingabe]
    print(uebersetzung)
```

This checks whether eingabe is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

`eingabe` is a string and `bedeutungen` is a dictionary, they can never be equal. You probably meant to use `in`:

```py
while not eingabe in bedeutungen:
```